# Cannot remove a file and I dont get a detailed ENOENT

Tags: node.js, fs

I am trying to accomplish a simple task, Delete a file. The error really doesn't tell me why it cannot delete the file. Any ideas on what it can be and how I can find out more of a detailed error in the future?

**My Code:**

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.unlink('/file/path.jpg', function(err){
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

**My Error:**

```
DEBUG: 

DEBUG: /Users/vartanarabyan/Development/NodeJS/orcha/routes/document.js:67

DEBUG:              if (err) throw err;

DEBUG:                    ^

DEBUG: Error: ENOENT, unlink '/Users/vartanarabyan/Development/NodeJS/orcha/public/uploads/5d78abfefd5ff47398103ada55d9be47'

DEBUG: Program node app exited with code 1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ENOENT` means `No such file or directory`. You are trying to delete a file that doesn't exist.

Comment: The File is at the exact path so that cant be true.

Comment: Your `unlink` references `path.jpg`, but the error only shows `../5d78abfefd5ff47398103ada55d9be47`. Do you need to add a `.jpg` extension, perhaps?

Comment: that was just an example path so i dont paste a long thing

Comment: Post `ls /Users/vartanarabyan/Development/NodeJS/orcha/public/uploads/` output.

Answer (score 3):

ok fixed the problem by using fs.unlinkSync(path)

Comment: I don't consider this a satisfactory resolution of the issue: if deleting the file only works if you block during the process, you've likely got an undetected race condition in your code and it will find another way to bite you later on. If you don't know *why* what you did seemed to fix the problem, you probably haven't actually fixed it. Unless this is "throwaway" code intended for one-time use, put some more thought into what's going on.

Comment: @ebohlman, it seems like if a finder/explorer has the directory open and the file you are trying to delete is present its considered being initiated and wont be deleted till that process is closed. Its kind of odd because the file is really not in use and not blocked.